# Implement a compare products funcionality

Tags: templating, frontend

I´m working in a buggy´s website, and i want to implement a "compare" functionality, where the clients can check some products from the list ( a checkbox in each product ) and be able to compare the products features side by side.

I think that i shold pass the array of values in the url from the checked products and in the compare page takes this values and filter the products. The only thing is that i don´t know how to implement it :)

Any help is welcome, thanks!

Sebastián.

Comment: Sounds like you're headed in the right direction! Admittedly, it's a very broad plan with a lot of details TBD. Which part are you getting hung up on specifically?

Comment: The list of products it´s no problem, i´m stuked in the checkbox part , collect the values from the checkbox activated ( i implement the validation of max 4 checked with jquery, no problem on that ) and send the values via url , when you click a button "Compare", and stucked on the compare page, how to "filter" those results ( the list of id´s sended via url ).